# vkbeatuify does not format xml

Tags: javascript, html

I've got such simple html. 
`vkbeatuify.js` is located in the same folder.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="vkbeautify.js"></script>
        <script>
            var variable = vkbeautify.xml("<root><cat></cat></root>"); 
            document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = variable;
        </script> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="data">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But when I open page in browser Firefox - it displays nothing.
What is the problem?

Comment: Why there be any visible output? `<root><cat></cat></root>` in browser looks same as `<div><span></span></div>`

Comment: Oh. So I need to use tags `pre`?

Comment: You need to replace `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;` to prevent parsing of XML/html elements in browser. You can still see output in DevTools.